# reverb effect using ffmpeg or any other command line

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am looking for a way to end a music track (that is cut in the middle) with a reverb effect - instead of a simple fade out.
Any idea how to do it using ffmpeg ? If not - other command line packages are also good.

Comment: Why don't you look for an audio package instead of one primarily video-based? Google 'audacity'.

Answer (score 0):

The
[FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)
contains this [example](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-6):

> Apply reverb to stream using mono IR file as second input, complete command using ffmpeg:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.wav -i middle_tunnel_1way_mono.wav -lavfi afir output.wav
> ```

Another [example](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-21)
says this:

> Add reverberation to the audio using TAP-plugins (Tom’s Audio Processing plugins):
>
> ```
> ladspa=file=tap_reverb:tap_reverb
> ```

(Not using ffmpeg, I can't help further than that.)